# Why is AddressSanitizer not show heap-use-after-free in nginx

Tags: c, nginx

I have test code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct Info {
    char *p;
    int num;
};


int main()
{
    struct Info *pInfo = (struct Info*)malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
    free(pInfo);
    printf("%d\n", pInfo->num);
    return 0; 
}
```

I compile and execute it with cmd:

```
gcc -O1 -g -fsanitize=address  test.c  -o t
```

The AddressSanitizer can output the error info  heap-use-after-free like:

```
==15552==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60200000eff8 at pc 0x47b4a1 bp 0x7fff17684ed0 sp 0x7fff17684ec8
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000eff8 thread T0
    #0 0x47b4a0 in main /home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/test.c:18
    #1 0x7f318a01a554 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x22554)
    #2 0x47b38c in _start (/home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/t+0x47b38c)

0x60200000eff8 is located 8 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x60200000eff0,0x60200000f000)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x465129 in free (/home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/t+0x465129)
    #1 0x47b465 in main /home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/test.c:17

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4652a9 in __interceptor_malloc (/home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/t+0x4652a9)
    #1 0x47b45a in main /home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/test.c:16

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /home/xiabaichuan/test_tmp/test.c:18 main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
```

However, when I copy the same test code in nginx http module, compile it and run, after send a http request to trigger code, the AddressSanitizer did not out put any heap-use-after-free error info, I compile NGINX cmd like:

```
gcc -o objs/nginx -L/home/xiabaichuan/master/cluster_live/TOOL/openresty-1.15.8.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -L/home/xiabaichuan/master/cluster_live/TOOL/openresty-1.15.8.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-recover=address -Wl,-E -Wl,-E -ldl -lcrypt -L/home/xiabaichuan/master/cluster_live/TOOL/openresty-1.15.8.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -lluajit-5.1 -lm -ldl -L/home/xiabaichuan/master/cluster_live/TOOL/openresty-1.15.8.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -lluajit-5.1 -lm -ldl -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz \
-Wl,-E
```

When I send an HTTP request to nginx, the printf shows a random number but AddressSanitizer does not output any error message; nginx prints like this:

```
[root@osboxes sbin]# ./nginx
788529154 (Tips:this num is a random error num)
```

nginx test code is like:

```
struct Info
{   
    int num;
};

static void
ngx_http_flv_live_cleanup(void *data)
{   
    ngx_rtmp_session_t       *s;
    
    s = data;
    
    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_INFO, s->connection->log, 0,
            "live:\"flv close connection\"");

    
    struct Info *pInfo = (struct Info *)malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
    pInfo->num = 2;
    free(pInfo);
    
    ngx_http_flv_live_close_session_handler(s);
    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_INFO, s->connection->log, 0,
            "live:\"flv close connection:%d\"", pInfo->num);
    printf("%d\n", pInfo->num);
    ngx_http_flv_live_close_session_handler(s);
}
```

When I curl a flv-http URL, this code may be executed, but this code: "printf("%d\n", pInfo->num);", doesn't show the heap-use-after-free, only print a random number.

Comment: The sanitizer is a "best effort" kind of tool. No guarantees.

Comment: `, pInfo->num);` compiler could have optimized this to just `, 2);`